# how to scroll draggable scrollbar sheet manually?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want a draggable scrollbar sheet that it has 2 text fields and one list below the text fields, But when I draggable scrollbar sheet is in its initial size and I try to click on the text field that sheet only scrolls to the text field but I have shown some of the list item below that filed. so how i can scroll a draggable scrollbar sheet with code like when the user taps on the text field then the sheet automatically scrolls?

Comment: Can you include current snippet

Comment: Do you mean snipping sheet?

Comment: yes from showModalBottomSheet sample widget, not full snippet ,that will reproduce the same issue, More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yes tried that but i want draggable functionality

Comment: Consider including your code-snippet for better understanding

Comment: sure, just wait a moment

Comment: unfortunately, I can share a code snippet. I just want to know how I can scroll the draggable scrollbar sheet manually like using a scroll controller or something. I tried animateTo and jumpTo method with draggableScrollController that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass controller and control default behavior

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true, // control manually
      builder: (context) {
        return DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (context, scrollController) {
            // use this `scrollController` for default 
            return ListView(
              controller:
                  scrollController, // you can pass custom controller
```